# Is it possible to specify a version range when using `yarn add`?

Tags: yarnpkg

- You can do `yarn add my-package` to install the latest version of my-package
- You can do `yarn add my-package@1.2.3` to install v1.2.3

Can you specify a range, like in package.json?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes.

I don't know why this isn't [documented explicitly](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/), but this works:

```bash
yarn add "express@^4.15.4"
# wrote "express": "^4.15.4" to package.json
# actually installed v4.17.1, which is latest satisfactory version
```

Comment: It doesn't for me. Yarn installs the exact given version and adds it to `package.json` without the `^`. E.g., `yarn add express@^4.15.4` ends up with `"express": "4.15.4";`.

Comment: Works for me if I put quotes around the dependency, as in `yarn add "express@^4.15.4"`

Comment: It's documented here: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-versions/#toc-version-ranges